# looking up for menu item in a menu bar in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make a menu item text change depending on isFullScreen property.

And found that:

```
isFullScreen.addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
        ((MenuItem) menuBar.lookup("#fullScreen"))
);
```

doesn't work, since lookup() returns a node, and MenuItem class extends Object.

is there an alternative method? what are possible workarounds? and just for curiosity, what could be the benefit of lookup method inside a Menu Bar?

Answer (score 3):

You need to listen to the `fullScreenProperty` of the `Stage`:

```
    primaryStage.fullScreenProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue) {
            System.out.println("Window is FULL SCREEN!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Window is NOT full screen!");
        }
    });
```

However, if you simply mean to check when the window is maximized (more common), then it's the `maximizedProperty` instead.

Comment: to Sysout() this is very easy, that's not what I meant, I meant that I want to change the label of an menuItem of a menuBar according to the isFullScreenProperty,
However I've found a workaround by using: `menuBar.getMenus().get(2).getItems().get(1).setText(newValue? "Exit Full Screen" : "Enter Full Screen");` but It needs me to know the location of the menuItem on the menuBar. (which is in this case in the 3rd menu, 2nd menuItem of that menu items)

Comment: @HocineAbdellatif Then you should keep a separate reference to the `MenuItem` you need to change. Or create a binding when you create the `MenuItem`, in which case [`Bindings.when`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when(javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue)) may be of interest to you.